# Modifying wordpress default search to custom search, code help needed

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, search-engine

I am working on WordPress, I am modiyfing the form to my new form, it has 3 fields as below

1. Default keyword field (named as s), this should also search in custom fields color, type, size
2. Category dropdown listing all parent & child categories
3. Year drop down, it has option 1950s, 1960s, 1970s etc, this will search for year in a custom field named "year", with each post, so if a post has year value 1964, is will show if you select 1960s from search form.

I don't know how do I do this, I tried below code snippet but didn't work for me.

```
<?php
echo $keyword=$_GET['s']. ', ';
echo $categoy=$_GET['cat']. ', ';
echo $decade=$_GET['model_era']. ', ';

$args = array( 's' => $keyword, 'cat' => $categoy, 's' => $keyword, 'post_status' => 'publish', 'post_type' => 'post', 'orderby' => 'meta_value', 'meta_key' => 'year', 'posts_per_page' => 3, 'paged' => $paged );
query_posts( $args );

?>
```

\
    
    
        
            
                Search Results - My page
                
                     id="post-">

*Posted on:* 
                            *by*

### No results found

Comment: try using $_REQUEST. Or define your query_var in function.php and use get_query_vars

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried any search plugins?

If not try this one [WP Custom Fields Search](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-custom-fields-search/) the css is not that great but it should give you the functionality you are looking for basically you can search for keywords, category and custom fields.

And for the default keyword to search every thing you should try [Search Everything](http://wordpress.org/plugins/search-everything/)

Comment: Thanks bhar

For WP Custom Fields Search plugin, it doesn't shows me parent category, I want to show parent and child categories together.